# Why does it work when columns are larger than rows in Python Sklearn (Linear Regression)

Tags: python, scikit-learn, linear-regression

I have 1200 row X 3000 columns .
I have known that the parameters cannot be estimated when columns are larger in Linear Regression.
Why does it work in Sklearn `LinearRegression()`?

Comment: Where did you read this? Do you confuse with SVM?

Comment: This is actually a good question, and the answer appears to be undocumented (perhaps because it's abstracted away via SciPy's `lstsq`). I suspect it's using the pseudo-inverse when the matrix is rank deficient, which finds the minimum l2 norm coeffiicents

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23714519/how-does-sklearn-do-linear-regression-when-p-n